# RAID 0 random read speed did not scale with the number of disks

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I did some RAID 0 performanace test On Dell PowerEdge 730xd.Info of the server is as follows:

- OS:CentOS 6.7
- Memeory:32 GB
- RAID controller:PERC H730P Mini (Embedded)

The command I used to test is iozone with 64GB file size to  eliminate disk cache:

```
iozone -Rab iozone_raid50_9.xls -s64G -i 0 -i 1 -i 2 -f /mnt/sdb/test -r 2048 -r 4096 -r 8192
```

The result is as follows:
[raid 0 test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgrEm.png)

the hdd num column is the number of hdd that form the RAID 0 array;

As you can see:

- sequence read/write and random write speed increase as hdd num increase;
- random read speed decrease as hdd num increase;

I'm confused why random read speed decrease,Can someone help explain it?

Comment: You use 'RADI' twice. Do you mean 'RAID' in both cases?